# Loop through SQL and calculate sum in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I have an issue with my code. I have 2 tables. First employee_id:

> |Employee id|
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

And the second table called employee_times:

> |Employee_id|Hours_dev|hours_pm|
>
> |1|2|3|
>
> |1|3|4|
>
> |2|3|3|

What I am trying to do is to calculate the total time that each employee has worked (hours_dev+hours_pm). For example employee_id 1 has worked 12 hours

So far I have tried to retrieve all the employee_id from the first table and use a for loop to go through the employee_times in an SQL statement (SEE CODE BELOW). However the code does not work as it prints 0 for both employee_id and total_hours.

I am using MYSQL on a localhost server.

> $sql = "SELECT employee_id FROM employee";
>                   $result = mysql_query($sql);
>                   while($row = mysql_fetch_array)
>                   {
>                       $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
>                   }

```
              $employee_id_length = sizeof($employee_id);

              for($i = 0; $i < $employee_id_length; $i++)
              {
                 $sql4 = "SELECT employee_id, hours_dev, hours_pm FROM employee_times WHERE employee_id= '$employee_id[$i]'";
                        $result =  mysql_query($sql4);
                          while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result));
                        {
                            $employee_id = $info['employee_id'];
                            $hours_dev=$info['hours_dev'];
                            $hours_pm=$info['hours_pm'];
                            $total_hours = ($total_hours + $hours_dev + $hours_pm );

                        }

                        //print "$employee_id worked for $total_hours";
              }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask a silly question, but why don't you do it in sql directly?

Comment: I agree with @Sebas it will be a lot quicker as well.

Comment: Is it possible to do it directly from sql? I want to find the sum of all the hours an employee has worked for each employee. e.g. you should end up with employee_id 1 has worked 6 hours, employee_id 2 has worked for 5 hours etc. I cannot think of another way of calculating the time for each employee in the table without some sort of iterator. I have tried SELECT employee_id, sum(hour_dev+hours_pm) FROM employee_times GROUP by employee_id but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get sum directly

```
 select employee_id, sum(hours_dev)+ sum(hours_pm) as total 
from employee_times WHERE employee_id= '1'
group by employee_id
```

refer this [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec91b/5)

Comment: does this deal with multiple rows of employee_id, hours_dev and hours_pm?

Comment: how would I get it so the result would show both employee 1 has worked 12 hours and employee 2 has worked 6 hours? This is the bit where Im having the most trouble and hence the for loop

Comment: i have modify the fiddle demo. check that

Comment: The modified version of the fiddle demo is exactly what Im looking for. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

this should get the data you need

```
SELECT
  hours_dev,
  hours_pm,
  sum(hours_dev) + sum(hours_pm) as total_hours
FROM
  employee_times
WHERE
  employee_id = 123
GROUP BY
  employee_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at aggregate functions:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query should pull the info much quicker than by script;

```
SELECT Employee_id, SUM(Hours_dev), SUM(Hours_pm), SUM(Hours_dev + Hours_pm) 
FROM employee_times 
GROUP BY Employee_id
```